Python with Pandas is not reading all records from a bit large CSV
I hope you can help me. When reading a slightly large CSV of 400 mb with Pandas, not all the records are being read. The url of the open data is: URL
With Pandas I can only read 1,189,096 records but the file has 1,216,582 including the header. The versions from previous days of that file were read completely and without problem, even without having to specify the "col_names", but since today it gave the error
"pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 32 fields in line 417545, saw 44" 

That's why I had to specify the columns but it doesn't read the entire file and doesn't give me error messages.
The code I use in python is:
col_names = ["N", "TIPO_SEGURO", "SEXO", "TIEMPO_EDAD", "EDAD", "ESTADO_CIVIL", "NIVEL_DE_INSTRUCCION", "ETNIA", "COD_UBIGEO_DOMICILIO", "PAIS_DOMICILIO", "DEPARTAMENTO_DOMICILIO", "PROVINCIA_DOMICILIO", "DISTRITO_DOMICILIO", "FECHA", "ANIO", "MES", "TIPO_LUGAR", "INSTITUCION", "MUERTE_VIOLENTA", "NECROPSIA", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_A", "CAUSA_A_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_B", "CAUSA_B_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_C", "CAUSA_C_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_D", "CAUSA_D_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_E", "CAUSA_E_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_F", "CAUSA_F_CIEX"]

tipo_de_datos = {"N":'int64', "TIPO_SEGURO":'string', "SEXO":'string', "TIEMPO_EDAD":'string', "EDAD":'string', "ESTADO_CIVIL":'string', "NIVEL_DE_INSTRUCCION":'string', "ETNIA":'string', "COD_UBIGEO_DOMICILIO":'string', "PAIS_DOMICILIO":'string', "DEPARTAMENTO_DOMICILIO":'string', "PROVINCIA_DOMICILIO":'string', "DISTRITO_DOMICILIO":'string', "FECHA":'string', "ANIO":'int64', "MES":'int64', "TIPO_LUGAR":'string', "INSTITUCION":'string', "MUERTE_VIOLENTA":'string', "NECROPSIA":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_A":'string', "CAUSA_A_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_B":'string', "CAUSA_B_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_C":'string', "CAUSA_C_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_D":'string', "CAUSA_D_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_E":'string', "CAUSA_E_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_F":'string', "CAUSA_F_CIEX":'string'}

df = pd.read_csv(file_csv, names=col_names, sep=",", low_memory=False,skiprows=1 ,dtype= tipo_de_datos)

df9 = df.groupby(['ANIO']).N.count()

print(df9)

print(df.shape[0]) # To know how many records Pandas has loaded

Please, if you can help me because I am running out of ideas, I have already used eliminating the "low_memory", eliminating the "dtype" and it does not change the result. I thank you in advance.

That's not a public URL. $ wget -S https://files.minsa.gob.pe/s/Ae52gBAMf9aKEzK/download/SINADEF_DATOS_ABIERTOS.csv reports "403 Forbidden". From what site may the general public download the data?

This CSV file contains formatting errors. The line 417545 is missing a closing double quotation mark, i.e. the line is
417544,SIS,FEMENINO,AÑOS,53,SOLTERO,SECUNDARIA INCOMPLETA,MESTIZO,92-33-09-02-01-000,PERU,HUANUCO,AMBO,AMBO,2023-01-31,2023,01,EESS,GOBIERNO REGIONAL,SIN REGISTRO,NO SE REALIZÓ NECROPSIA,"DIABETES MELLITUS NO ESPECIFI,E147,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO

where it probably should be
417544,SIS,FEMENINO,AÑOS,53,SOLTERO,SECUNDARIA INCOMPLETA,MESTIZO,92-33-09-02-01-000,PERU,HUANUCO,AMBO,AMBO,2023-01-31,2023,01,EESS,GOBIERNO REGIONAL,SIN REGISTRO,NO SE REALIZÓ NECROPSIA,"DIABETES MELLITUS NO ESPECIFI",E147,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO,SIN REGISTRO

("DIABETES MELLITUS NO ESPECIFI")
There are more formatting errors in lines further down the file. You can try to correct them manually or try to ask the provider of the file to correct them, since this is not a valid CSV file.

Thank you very much @asdf, with a program that reads the file at low level I removed the double quotes and pandas was able to read all the records without having to specify the col_names. I suggest that Pandas or Python should report that it has skipped some records when using names=col_names, so that we developers can have an alert to check.
